# angular 11 routing problem in lazy loaded module

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, lazy-loading

information: my project has a modules folder contain ten feature modules with lazy loading routing and every feature modules has several sub module.

problem: when the code navigate to some feature modules everything is ok but when I refresh page or manually navigate to that URL, it run target feature module for a moment then back to its feature module without any error. it just happen for some feature modules and other work ok.
example: financial is a feature module and verify-payment is its sub module
when I manually go to http://localhost:4200/financial/verify-payment it show verify-payment page then after a moment it redirect to http://localhost:4200/financial

app-routing.module.ts file:

```
const routes: Routes = [

  {
    path: "courses", loadChildren:
      () => import('./modules/courses/courses.module').then(m => m.CoursesModule)
  },
  {
    path: "financial", loadChildren:
      () => import('./modules/financial/financial.module').then(m => m.FinancialModule)
  },
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
]
```

financial-routing.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { FinancialDocsComponent } from './components/financial-docs/financial-docs.component';
import { FactorComponent } from './components/factor/factor.component';
import { VerifyPaymentComponent } from './components/verify-payment/verify-payment.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: FinancialDocsComponent },
  { path: 'factor', component: FactorComponent },
  { path: 'verify-payment', component: VerifyPaymentComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class FinancialRoutingModule { }
```

courses-routing.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { CourseListComponent } from './components/course-list/course-list.component';
import { CourseTypeComponent } from './components/course-type/course-type.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'course-list', component: CourseListComponent },
  { path: '', component: CourseTypeComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class CoursesRoutingModule { }
```

CourseListComponent, FactorComponent and VerifyPaymentComponent are a new component without any code

everything in course list is ok but I have problem with factor and verify-payment

Comment: Can you share you routing code or module?

Comment: Kindly share code Hassan. Like your Routing File where main routing is defined and then sub routing file of feature module. Without code nobody would be able to help you properly

Comment: @WahabShah ok I'll edit it

Comment: I recreated this project structure for me locally. Everything works perfect. How do your FinancialModules and CoursesModule look like?

Comment: I created a StackBlitz for you, you can check that every routing is working properly and you can tell us, what you did wrong. This way we all learn. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wmezxc

Comment: @JanosVinceller I did it before and everything was ok for me too. this is a large scale project and I'm not sure which part have problem. do you have any idea to analysis routing action ? or some way to debug this issue

Comment: It is always a good thing to reduce complexity in large scale projects. Reduce it one by one, in worst case to the smallest working thing. You'll see the error by reducing step by step or after adding things back again.

Comment: @JanosVinceller ok I try it. I'll update my question after solving it. thank you

Comment: @hassanyousefi I think only it redirects to cause somewhere in code you are redirecting at some condition happen. like inside interceptors, route guards, resolvers, or from related component.

Comment: @GRD yes exactly. I found problem, it there was in a service that called in interceptor service and navigate to other path.

Comment: @JanosVinceller your idea solved my problem. thank you!

Comment: That's nice, I'm happy about it. I was even happier if you could edit your question, so that it helps others. After that give your own solution as an answer to help others quickly find their problem. You can completely rewrite your question if that's needed. That would be greatly appreciated.